# How to avoid to hide element of the page behind a fixed element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a fixed navbar on the top of the website. The problem is the following, if I use the `position: fixed;` CSS property, the page goes under my navbar, and I'd like to avoid it to happen, here's the whole navbar code :

```css
nav a {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    nav li {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    nav li a {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .margin-left-50 {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

    .nav-title {
        font-size: 35px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .margin-top-connect {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="../cinefilms/sources/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="../cinefilms/sources/jquery.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark fixed-top blacknavbar navbar-tunning">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand nav-title margin-right-title margin-left-50"><font color="#888888">Ciné</font><font color="red">Films</font></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="../cinefilms/main.php">Accueil<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="../cinefilms/review_list.php">Toutes nos Reviews<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Rechercher" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Rechercher</button>
        </form>
        <li>
            <button onclick=window.location.href="#" class="navbar-opt btn btn-outline-primary margin-top-connect">Connexion</button>
        </li>
        <div>
</nav>
<div class="header-casse"></div>
```

Notice that I also use Bootstrap functions, and bootstrap JS and Jquery to collapse my navbar.
I include this navbar in another page, and the CSS are called in theses pages. You don't have to mind the fact that you don't see the call.

I look forward for you help. Thx

Comment: Do you want the Nav bar to permanently be visible while you scroll? or just at the top of the page, i.e before all the other content?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if how you want the navbar to behave when the user scrolls.

**If you want the navbar to always be visible whilst scrolling, but to not cover the top section of the page.**
 then you should just add some padding to the top of the page e.g.  that is the height of the navbar. then all the content in the body will be visible as it will be pushed down below the navbar.

or

**if you just want the navbar to be at the top of the page**
then you shouldn't need to do any CSS (depending on what's already there), just restructure the HTML so that the navbar comes before the rest of the content

Comment: The solution i'm looking for is the 1st case, but I can't find any way to add a padding to my whole page, do you have any code or any link to a solution?

Comment: You can add a padding to the body of the page (using css). Make sure the padding is at leasst the height of your navbar, then it should be visisble